# Convert string into array and do operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string like: `"1234567334535674326774324423"`. I need to create a method to do the following:

1. Make an array consisting of digits in the string like `[1, 2, 3, ..., 2, 3]`
2. Sum all the odd positions of the array
3. Sum all the even positions of the array
4. Multiply the odd sum by 3
5. Sum step 4 and step 3.
6. Get the minimum number to sum to step 5 to get the sum that is a multiple of 5.

I don't know how to solve this with rails. If anyone can help me, I would be glad.

I have this:

```
barcode_array = @invoice.barcode.each_char.map {|c| c.to_i}
impares = [barcode_array[0]] + (1...barcode_array.size).step(2).collect { |i| barcode_array[i] }
pares = (2...barcode_array.size).step(2).collect { |i| barcode_array[i] }
suma_impares = impares.inject(:+)
mult_impares = suma_impares * 3
suma total = mult_impares + pares
```

Comment: It feels like an assignment task, and you don't need the rails framework for it, you can easily do it in ruby, please show your effort or some work before asking for help

Comment: Its not. Its the way to calculate the verification number of Argentine Invoices that must be included in the barcode. http://www.formularioscontinuos.com/digito.html

Comment: @Subash Its not. Its the way to calculate the verification number of Argentine Invoices that must be included in the barcode. formularioscontinuos.com/digito.html

Comment: ok I stand corrected so where are you stuck ?

Comment: One of my problems is that i need to consider the "0" index like a odd position. And also dont know how to do the comparison in 6)

Comment: Iam looking to a fast solution also, because mine its very low

Comment: @Subash I edited my question with what i found, i didnt test it yet because i need the last step .Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Can you explain you step `6)` I dont understand what you require there.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is the code if anyone needs it:

```
barcode_array = @invoice.barcode.each_char.map {|c| c.to_i}
impares = [barcode_array[0]] + (1...barcode_array.size).step(2).collect { |i| barcode_array[i] }
pares = (2...barcode_array.size).step(2).collect { |i| barcode_array[i] }
suma_impares = impares.inject(:+).to_i
mult_impares = suma_impares * 3
suma_pares = pares.inject(:+).to_i
suma_total = mult_impares + suma_pares
verificador = 10 - (suma_total - (suma_total / 10).to_i * 10)
@invoice.barcode = @invoice.barcode.to_s + verificador.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean in step 6, but here's how I would tackle 1-5:

```
s = '1234567334535674326774324423'
a = s.chars.map(&:to_i) # convert to an array of integers

odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0

# sum up odds and evens
a.each_with_index {|n, i| n.even? ? even_sum += n : odd_sum += n}

total = even_sum + odd_sum * 3
```